# var_dump() in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there any convenient way to dump all members of a specified object in Scala,
like [`var_dump()`, PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)?

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in "[How to Dump/Inspect Object or Variable in Java](http://eclipsedriven.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-dumpinspect-object-or-variable.html)" (yes, I know, the question is about Scala):

> Scala (console) has a very useful feature to inspect or dump variables / object values :

```
scala> def b = Map("name" -> "Yudha", "age" -> 27)
b: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Any]

scala> b
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Any] = Map((name,Yudha), (age,27))
```

But if you want more details, you can give [REPL Scala Utils](https://bitbucket.org/eengbrec/scala-repl-utils/wiki/Home) a try, in order to get a "[Easier object inspection in the Scala REPL](http://erikengbrecht.blogspot.com/2010/12/easier-object-inspection-in-scala-repl.html)"

> So I've written a utility for use on the Scala REPL that will **print out all of the "attributes" of an object**.

(Note: "I" being here: [**Erik Engbrecht**](http://www.blogger.com/profile/11174963559600768092), also [on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/eengbrec))

> Here's some sample usage:

```
scala> import replutils._
import replutils._

scala> case class Test(a: CharSequence, b: Int)
defined class Test

scala> val t = Test("hello", 1)
t: Test = Test(hello,1)

scala> printAttrValues(t)
hashCode: int = -229308731
b: int = 1
a: CharSequence (String) = hello
productArity: int = 2
getClass: Class = class line0$object$$iw$$iw$Test
```

> That looks fairly anti-climatic, but after spending hours typing `objName` to see what's there, and poking at methods, it seems like a miracle.
>   Also, one neat feature of it is that if the class of the object returned is different from the class declared on the method, it prints both the declared class and the actual returned class.

Comment: and how does one display all the variables in the environment?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [ToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) in commons-lang, specificly [`ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html#reflectionToString%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 2):

In compiled code, the nicest way is usually just to declare your type as a case class, then use the generated `toString` method.

Anything else subclassing `Product` should be just as easy (currently just tuples)

Failing that, write your own `toString` method, it's usually trivial enough...